# Is it possible to export application from android studio as an ios app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to write app for ios with java is it possible ?
Can i do it with android studio ?
If i cant which is the best way for writing app in java for ios ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to write a native ios app in java.  You will have to use a mobile development framework.  This used to be RoboVM but that is now winding down.  The RoboVM devs recommend moving to libGDX and the Intel Multi-OS Engine.

Another option is to learn C# and use Xamarin studio to support several mobile platforms from a single codebase.

See [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3925) for a discussion of options, none of which are without a learning curve.